# Is there a single subscription stream, which doesn't throw an exception. Instead it cancels the old subscription automatically?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxjs, rx-java2

The title pretty much describes everthing. I am finding myself often doing this:

```
  StreamSubscription willDismissPageStreamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    willDismissPageStreamSubscription?.cancel();
    willDismissPageStreamSubscription =
        bloc.willDismissPageStream(widget.pageIndex).listen((willDismiss) {});
  }
```

I listen to a stream in a method that can be called multiple times. If I would not cancel the subscription it would create a new one everytime I initState is called. I am wondering if there is a Stream, who allows this, everytime a new StreamSubscription is created through calling listen, the old subscription is canceled:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
        bloc.willDismissPageStream(widget.pageIndex).listen((willDismiss) {});
  }
```

EDIT: I am searching more or less for a Single-Subscription-Stream, but instead of throwing an exception it should cancle the last StreamSubscription.

EDIT 2: If such a Stream doesn't exist, how would I create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you don't want new subscriptions to mutate older subscriptions. It makes observables difficult to reason about.

This is a serial pattern, which is generally implemented using a [SerialDisposable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/disposables/SerialDisposable.java). Calling `set` atomically cancels the previous subscription.

```
  SerialDisposable serial = new SerialDisposable();

  @override
  void initState() {
       serial.set(bloc.willDismissPageStream(widget.pageIndex).listen((willDismiss) {}));
  }
```

If you want this behavior in an Observable, you can send a completed notification instead of an error which causes a pipeline teardown, but it's not something I'd recommend.